# What are the criteria for being considered a British citizen by descent?

Tags: united-kingdom, citizenship

I am a British citizen who was under 18 when my father applied for naturalization in 1979. I (as well as my father) was then given citizenship when the naturalization came through in 1982.

Am I a British citizen by descent or not?

Comment: I believe you are a British citizen otherwise than by descent, but the [British Nationality Act 1981](https://www.legislation.gov.uk/ukpga/1981/61) is very complicated indeed.

Comment: There are a few users on [Expatriates.SE] who may be able to offer an authoritative answer.